# Using 'argparse' as opposed to sys.argv

Tags: python, argparse, argv

My script currently uses `sys.argv` to check for an input file provided to the program.

I am trying to utilise `argparse` instead but I cant seem to get it to work. I was able to set it up and add an argument, but when I parse an argument, and print that parsed argument, I get a namespace. How can I get a string? Basically, I want to take the argument as a string, and open a file with that name.

Currently, my `sys.argv` is:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
f = open(filename, 'r')
```

My `argparse` prints out a `Namespace` as follows:

```
arg = parser.parse_args()
print arg
```

How can I use that to open a file? I want to use `argparse` since the error handlign for arguments there is a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

think its preferable (or something!) to use the `with` statement to open the file like this:

```
# printfile.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Opens a file and does cool stuff ^^")
parser.add_argument('filename', type=str, help="Path to file to open")
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.filename) as f:
    print '   my uber cool file:'
    print f.readlines()
```

specifying those keyword args also helps make a pretty -h help text option (which is neat neat)

```
[dlam@dlam-63221:~] $ python printfile.py -h
usage: printfile.py [-h] filename

Opens a file and does cool stuff ^^

positional arguments:
    filename    Path to file to open
```

Comment: That actually solved my problem with error handling that I was about to ask (with the `with` statement). Thanks!

Comment: `with` is a context manager.  It guarantees (baring a segmentation fault within the interpreter itself I suppose) that when you exit the context (even with an exception), that the object used to create the context will be finalized properly.  In other words, your file will be correctly closed and those resources will be freed no matter what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Print `arg` followed by a dot followed by whatever name you assigned to the argument in the `argparse` setup.

Example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Title you want')
parser.add_argument('-f', action = "store", dest = "fflag", type = str, help = "Filename to be used, stdin is default")
```

In this case, the file name will be preceded by `-f` on the command line and will be accessible by `parser.fflag` of type `str`

Comment: So argparse basically puts all the arguments in a dictionary? Also, doing that and printing the file returns: `<open file 'test', mode 'r' at 0x1004e46f0>`. Does that mean that the file is already opened by argparse?

Comment: @Darksky - It is actually a custom object and not a plain dict. And if you typed the arg as a file, then it will conveniently give you an already opened file object. You could type is as a str and get back just a string with no file validation if you wanted.

Comment: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/argparse/ This was a good tutorial I found. You basically setup your arguments and assign them to variable if you want allowing access later on in your program. I'll update my answer with an example.